# How to upload files to specific folder multer-ftp on remote server?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

Using this code I try send files on remote server:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: new ftpStorage({
        basepath: '/uploads/',

        ftp: {
            host: 'samplehost.com',
            secure: false, // enables FTPS/FTP with TLS
            user: 'login',
            password: 'password'
        }
    })
});
```

but always save file in root directory, not in uploads, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multer-ftp, Uploading Files to remote server using multer-sftp is easy and flexible way. also we can upload the files to remote server with scp, ssh techniques in node js.

Working Code:

```
exports.newFileUpload =  function(req , res , next){

   // sftp settings     
    var storage = sftpStorage({
      sftp: {
        host: 'hostname',
        port: 22,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'

      },
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'images/') // designation folder in host
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // file name settings
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
      }
    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');

    upload(req,res,function(err){
        logger.debug(JSON.stringify(req.body));
              logger.debug(JSON.stringify(req.files));
          if(err){
               logger.debug("Error Occured", JSON.stringify(err));
               res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
          } else{
               logger.debug("Files uploaded successfully");
              res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
          }
      });
}
```

Note: When using 'multer-sftp' port no 22 is open in remote server.

Official Documentation [multer-sftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-sftp)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Whilst links to external resources may be valuable, you are expected to explain and include the essence of the answer directly in your post on SO. Please do so.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko. thanks for your suggestion, i've updated the answer